# Move where JSON promise response is returned

Tags: javascript, json

I have some code which works perfectly, except that it is returning the code inside the wrong function. It gets returned in my reporthandler but I need it in myfunction because that is where I need to process it.

Here is my code:

```
function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportID, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0))
    // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO GET MY DATA RETURNED
      });
}


function reportHandler(id, r2, retries){
    if(retries >= 3){return}
    if (r2.error == "report_not_ready") {
        console.log("Not ready");
        setTimeout(function() {
          getReport(id, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(id, r2, retries + 1))
        }, 2000);
      }
      // THIS IS NOT WHERE I WANT MY DATA BUT WHERE IT COMES OUT
      console.log(r2);
}

function getReport(ref, type, granularity, from, to, metric, element) {
  return $.getJSON("report.php", {
    ref: ref,
    type: type,
    granularity: granularity,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    metric: metric,
    element: element,
  });
}
```

This is the closest I am able to get:

```
function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportId, "get").done((r2) => {
      reportHandler(r1.reportId, r2, 0);
      console.log(r2);
    });
  });
}
```

How can I collect the result of my JSON response from the API into the "myfunction" so that I can process it within that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `async`/`await` for this.

Rather than chaining together promises, you can use `await` to wait for their completion. I've added a `sleep` function that "waits X milliseconds" to replace your `setTimeout` (by using a `setTimeout` of its own).

```js
const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));

async function myfunction(ref) {
  var r1 = await getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page");
  var r2 = await getReport(r1.reportID, "get").then(r2 => reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0));
  
  console.log(r2);
}

async function reportHandler(id, r2, retries) {
  if (retries >= 3 || r2.error != "report_not_ready") return r2;
  
  await sleep(2000);                              //Wait 2 seconds
  var report = await getReport(id, "get");        //Try again
  return reportHandler(id, report, retries + 1);  //Until we get a result
}

function getReport(ref, type, granularity, from, to, metric, element) {
  return $.getJSON("report.php", {
    ref: ref,
    type: type,
    granularity: granularity,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    metric: metric,
    element: element,
  });
}
```

---

Here's some working scratch code that calls a JSON endpoint, simulating a few retries before a successful result.

```js
const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));

async function myfunction(ref) {
  var r1 = await getReport();
  var r2 = await getReport().then(r2 => reportHandler(r2, 0));
  console.log(r2);
}

async function reportHandler(r2, retries) {
  if (retries >= 3) return r2;
  console.log(`Attempt #${retries+1} failed. Retrying in 2 seconds.`);
  
  await sleep(2000);
  var report = await getReport();
  return reportHandler(report, retries + 1);
}

function getReport() {
  return $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
}

myfunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tyler this is so perfect, I really wanted to use async but couldn't get my head around it

Comment: Glad to have helped. I've edited my code slightly to collapse `r2` onto one line. It felt strange to declare it, only to knowingly reset it on the next line regardless of outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to promisify your `reportHandler` with something like this:

```
const myfunction = ref =>
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-09-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").then(r1 =>
    getReport(r1.reportId, "get").then(r2 =>
      reportHandler(r1.reportId, r2, 0).then(r3 => {
        console.log(r1,r2,r3);
      })
    );
  );

const reportHandler = (id, r2, retries) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(retries >= 3) { resolve() }
      if (r2.error == "report_not_ready") {
        console.log("Not ready");
        setTimeout(function() {
          return getReport(id, "get").then(r2 => reportHandler(id, r2, retries + 1)).then(r => resolve(r))
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
```

You have `setTimeout` which you would need to wait for. See if this approach works for you.

Comment: Thank you for this - it looks very helpful. I'm having a hard time using it as I get a syntax error on this line ```return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {``` - i dont suppose you can help me understand why so I can try it please?

Comment: See if the updated version would work out of the box. It is tricky to test this so you would have to play with it and tailor for your needs but bottom line is you have a promise chain you need to work with and setTimeout needs to be inside a promise.